# What does "know on" mean?

Tags: phrases

My business partner, who is a Native English speaker, used "***know on***" in the email.

The sentence is:

> Now they has found out the reason why they kept asking for the delay, it turns out he ***know on*** of the their competitive units called ●●●.

I am not sure why he used "on".

Comment: “he know”? “on of the their”? We have to consider the possibility that this email was typed by your partner’s cat. At the very least, it’s possible that the sentence was meant to read “he knows ***one*** of …”.

Comment: I suspect that there is a typo or two or three involved.

Comment: Are you sure he wasn't saying "In the know on" ?  That is an idiom that basically means "knowing something secret" (or being one of a limited number of people aware of a plan or activity etc.)

Comment: or more particularly "he's in the know on" or "I'm in the know on".

Comment: There are too many mistakes for these to be typos of a "native English speaker". There has to be some translation software being used somewhere here. I think @Tom22 is right, and the idiom is "in the know on".

Comment: Thank you for your answering,Mr/Ms Scott, Hot Licks, Tom22 and geokavel.
According all your comments, it sounds just typo..
Sometimes it is difficult for me to judge it's just typo or the phrase what I don't know.
Again, thank you very much :)

Comment: The text is atrocious.  Voting to close as NARQ.

Comment: @Kris I can understand what you mean because it was just typo.
However I think it could be helpful for someone who have similar question.
It could be happen someone do same mistake and it could be possible this question will be help for him/her.
So I would like to remain it. I am sorry if my understanding is wrong.
Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

To give your Native English speaking business partner the benefit of the doubt, the multiple grammatical errors in this email could be the fault of auto-correction.

As a Millenial™, I consider myself a Native speaker of auto-corrected English. I believe this **could** be what your partner was trying to say:

> **Now,** they **have** found out the reason why they kept asking for the delay; it turns out he **knows** **of** their competitive units called...

Comment: Thank you for your answering @as4s4hetic
Now I learn that I have to doubt grammar mistakes if it is written by English speaker..
Yes, I also do typo in my native language too..^^;
Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad to be of help :) @Momoko

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo. I *suspect* the sentence is meant to read as:

> Now they **have** found out the reason why they kept asking for the delay. It turns out, he **knows one** of <s>the</s> their competitive units (is?) called ...

Even in this somewhat-corrected form, the grammar is a bit cumbersome, but from the little context provided, this seems the most logical answer.

We can make guesses all day, but to answer your question: **"Know on"** means nothing, it's a typo. One of many in that email, I'm sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answering @Sinjai.
It's helpfull for me to learn "Know on" doesn't have the specific meaning.
It sounds like his typo but it was good opportunity for my studying.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Momoko No problem. Feel free to hit that upvote button if I helped. ^.^